# Amazon EC2 instance(T2 micro Free Tier) giving 503 Service Unavailable error

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, server, http-status-code-503

We created a Amazon EC2 instance(T2 micro Free Tier) last week. We installed Apache2, PHP and mysql. The site was working fine until today. Suddenly the MySql service and apache2 service stopped working. After restarting the instance and restarting the apache2 service, it started showing 503 Service Unavailable error. There is no load balancer implemented.

What could be the possible reason for this, and how can we fix it?

NOTE: we were testing with audio files, and during testing, downloaded multiple audio files simultaneously using ajax(total of around 200mb). The above issues happened after this.

We have checked the disk space and memory. The server has enough space. The instance also shows no error. We can access the server and mysql through ssh. But the site remains unavailable.

EDIT: [CPU utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWzhs.png)

Comment: Did you check CPU utilization in monitoring tab?...since its t2 micro CPU utilization may reached its peak. You can share monitoring graph in question.

Comment: @ArpitJain I have added the CPU utilization graph in description.

Comment: With this much information i could only guess about the problem. You can ssh into the instance and look for the logs to see what's going wrong. I still suspect on the disk spaces which might keeping your services from being able to run, so you can try cleaning some spaces like removing old logs data and restart the instance.

Comment: As t2 instances are considered burstable, You should also check for the CPU credit metrics in cloudwatch metric console:- `CPUCreditUsage`, `CPUCreditBalance`, `CPUSurplusCreditBalance`, `CPUSurplusCreditsCharged`. Once credit reach 0, they can be throttled to a very low amount of CPU resources.